# Tax benefits to buying stocks on Dec 31 vs. one day later?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, investing, income-tax

For an individual in the US (California), are there tax benefits to buying stocks on Dec 31 vs. one day later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a long term gain you must hold the stock a year and a day, so, the long term hold period will fall into 2015 regardless. This is the only tax related issue that occurs to me, did you have something else in mind?

Welcome to Money.SE.

Comment: maybe something about wash sales?

Comment: @CQM - Well, you're really digging now. If he sold a stock at a loss 30 days before Dec 31, it would create a wash sale if he doesn't wait till Jan 2. But that issue can happen on any decision to buy. Nothing magic about 12/31.